# Google Sheets to Google Calendar App Script Help/Review

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a script where it takes dates from my Google sheet (columns `H`, `I`, `J`, `K`, and `AC`) and posts them into my Google Calendar with a custom title.

This is kind of set up in a way where if I change the dates in the sheet, it should delete the previously created event and add the new one.

I adapted the code from [GimelG's answer on the bottom here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ukTEz78boFU).

So far, with the script below, I'm starting off with getting the dates in column `I`. But I would like help with trying to do all of the other date columns as well.

I'm also trying to get the custom naming of events to be as follows:

> [Project Code - column E] + [Document Type - column G] + [Column Name its being taken from, so for column I it would be "File Date"].

I appreciate all and any help I can get to get this to work!

Right now I get a `createAllDayEvent` error.

> Cannot find method createAllDayEvent(string,string,object). (line 30,
>   file "Copy of addToCal")

Here is my [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y8ZHfdfzznhyMYu-mkWLZFMFEVIxMvh6za6aRWddfsc/edit?usp=sharing).

Below is the script I'm trying to fix and improve on:

```
function addToCal() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
    sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
    range = sheet.getActiveRange(),
    row = range.getRow(),
    data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 40).getValues(),
    date = data[0][8],
    today = new Date(),
    startDate = new Date(today.setMonth(today.getMonth()-1)),
    endDate = new Date(today.setMonth(today.getMonth()+6)),
    calId = 'example@example.com',
    cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId),
    events = cal.getEvents(startDate, endDate),
    titles = [];

  for (var i = 0, len = events.length; i < len; i++)
    titles.push(events[i].getTitle());

  var order = (data[0][1] + ' - ' + data[0][4] + ' - ' +data[0][6] + ' to ' + data[0][2]),
    index = titles.indexOf(order),
    ok = 1;
  if (index > -1)
  {
    var eventDate = events[index].getAllDayStartDate();
    if (date =='') return events[index].deleteEvent();

    if (eventDate.getTime() == date.getTime()) var ok = 0;
    else events[index].deleteEvent();
  }
  if (ok)
    cal.createAllDayEvent(order, date, {location: data[0][2]}).removeAllReminders();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you put the full error message in your question? That seems pretty relevant.

Comment: 'Cannot find method createAllDayEvent(string,string,object). (line 30, file "Copy of addToCal")'

Comment: Looks like `date`  is a string not a `Date`. Try using the Date constructor like this `date=new Date(data[0][8]);`

Comment: @Cooper Thank you, that has removed the error message. I really thought my code would work after this, but now I have to figure out why it doesn't post to my Calendar.

Comment: You seem to have two declarations for `ok` the first is 1 and the second is 0.  Perhaps the second one is keeping you from creating event.

Comment: @Cooper thank you. I tried that, but still doesn't produce a result.       
I did notice that I was referencing [0][8] before which I believe has been calling the column header and not the value. So I changed it to [1][8].       
When I do that I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property "8" from undefined. (line 2, file "addToCal")`

              
btw, is it normal to edit the question with the suggestions you have been giving me?

Comment: Since your using getActiveRange then you have to select the range that you want before calling the function.  There's only one row in your range so data[1][8] doesn't exist. It's okay with me but I don't guarantee that they will work.

Comment: Maybe I'm suffering a stroke, but how does [1][8] not exist? Isn't [1][8] = `8/24/2018`?     And how do I properly select it? Just by cell or can I just crtl + a everything?

Comment: Your code says `data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 40).getValues();` so data.length is 1.  So data[0] exists.  data[1] doesn't.

Comment: @Cooper could you please help me get this to work. I'm afraid I am not doing this correctly and would appreciate it. I just this script to sync the dates in my Google sheet to my calendar.

Comment: I correct some coding errors in your spreadsheet.  You can probably debug it now.